# How to extract parts of an expression using Cases

Tags: evaluation, pattern-matching, filtering

Let the following `exprs` stand for a list of *complicated* expressions which we are interested in breaking down into parts by extracting a number of individual subcomponents, from each expression:

```
exprs = {f1["b", f2[1], head1["a", 14] f3["c", head2[12, 3], head1["b", 8]]] head2[2, 8], f2[5]};
```

The patterns we are interested in are of the following forms:

```
patts = {head1["a", x1_], head2[x2_,y_]};
```

Now, here comes what is troubling me:

- The *obvious way* ( to me ) to extract the desired parts ( here `x1`, `x2` and `y`) is to use `Cases`:

  ```
  Cases[exprs, #->{x1, x2, y}, Infinity]& /@ patts
  ```

which in turn returns a list of the requested parts per expression

> ```
> {{{14,x2,y}} ,{{x1,12,3}, {x1,2,8}}}
> ```

This way of getting the requested parts out is not *productive* in the sense that when having to extract 10 or 20 parts or more, providing `Cases` with an exhaustive list is a no-go. I need something more automated.

One possible solution I could come up with was to use something like `syms = Cases[patts, p_Pattern :> p[[1]], Infinity]` to extract beforehand all the symbols associated with the desired subexpressions, since the patterns are handcoded and are known before the extraction 'starts'. The amended `Cases` and its return value are shown below

```
Cases[exprs, #->syms, Infinity]& /@ patts
```

> ```
> {{{14,x2,y}}, {{x1,12,3}, {x1,2,8}}}
> ```

This is still not 100% usable because it would be nice if there were a way to *postprocess* the extracted subexpressions *after* they are identified.

One possible way to do that is

```
Cases[exprs, # -> postproc[syms], Infinity]& /@ patts
```

which evaluates to

> ```
> {{postproc[{14,x2,y}]}, {postproc[{x1,12,3}], postproc[{x1,2,8}]}}
> ```

which *seems* to do the trick, but brakes down as soon as I try to define `postproc` in a way I find useful, eg. as in the following sense.

```
keys=ToString /@ syms;
postproc[x_, h_: keys] := AssociationThread[h -> x]
```

> ```
> {{<|"x1"->x1,"x2"->x2,"y"->y|>},
>      {<|"x1"->x1,"x2"->x2,"y"->y|>, |<|"x1"->x1,"x2"->x2,"y"->y|>}}
> ```

As anyone can see, as soon as `postproc` gets a definition the output is not evaluated in the desired way.

I've tried several iterations for the definition of `postproc` along with interchanging `Rule` with `RuleDelayed` in the second argument of `Cases`. The only thing I could come up that works is `Hold`ing the head of `postproc`.

```
Cases[exprs, #->Hold[postproc][syms],Infinity] & /@ patts // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> {{<|"x1"->14,"x2"->x2,"y"->y|>},
>      {<|"x1"->x1,"x2"->12,"y"->3|>, <|"x1"->x1,"x2"->2,"y"->8|>}}
> ```

OK, so this works but I don't know if there's a better/more intuitive/more paradigmatic way to code something like this.

Please help, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One part of the problem has already been mentioned by @C.E. in his answer: Since `Association` is seen as atomic by the pattern matcher, no insertion of matched expressions happens within it.

The reason this is a problem at all is that your `postproc` is not actually evaluated after the matches have been identified, but *before*. To prevent evaluation of the right side of the replacement rule before the match has been found, you can use [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) (`:>`)

```
With[
 {syms = syms},
 Cases[exprs, # :> postproc[syms], Infinity] & /@ patts
 ]
(* {
    {<|"x1" -> 14, "x2" -> x2, "y" -> y|>},
    {<|"x1" -> x1, "x2" -> 12, "y" -> 3|>, <|"x1" -> x1, "x2" -> 2, "y" -> 8|>}
   } *)
```

Note the use of `With` to insert the value of `syms` into the now held right side of the rule (if `syms` were to be evaluated after the match is found, nothing would be inserted, since `x1`, `x2`, etc. need to be literally present in the replacement).

Comment: so please let me see if I get it right: using `RuleDelayed` *without* injecting anything (not using `With`) does not allow `syms` to evaluate to their `OwnValues` because `RuleDelayed` `Hold`s its second argument (its `Attributes` contain `HoldRest`); this way, when something matches, `postproc` is called with `syms` which eventually gets evaluated to its *unbound* `OwnValues`; on the other hand, using `With` is-essentially-like *manually* supplying `postproc` with the `OwnValues` of `syms`; this way, when a match is found, the RHS of the rule is evaluated with the *bound* values

Comment: @yosimitsukodanuri That exactly what is happening, yes

Answer (score 3):

A possible workaround:

```
keys = ToString /@ syms;
postproc[x_, h_: keys] := Thread[h -> x]

Association @@@ Cases[exprs, # -> postproc[syms], Infinity] & /@ patts
```

> {{<|"x1" -> 14, "x2" -> x2, "y" -> y|>}, {<|"x1" -> x1, "x2" -> 12,
>   "y" -> 3|>, <|"x1" -> x1, "x2" -> 2, "y" -> 8|>}}

Comment: Please explain how that works because I'm not sure I understand how it applies to the problem

Comment: @yosimitsukodanuri well, it applies to the problem in the sense that it gets the same answer that you were expecting from your method. The problem is that symbol replacement in `Association` doesn't work the way you'd expect because `Association` is atomic (in theory, WRI may not be consistent about this).  So instead I use a list first, which is not atomic and supports replacements, and then convert the list structure to associations at the last moment.

Comment: oh, ok now I saw what you did with `Thread`; thank you for the workaround and for pointing out that the '*problem*' I am dealing with is due to the atomic nature of `Association`