# Does passing patterns between packages alter their name unbeknownst to the user?

Tags: pattern-matching, packages, filtering, scoping

This question is a partial followup to my [*previous*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/210171/how-to-extract-parts-of-an-expression-using-cases) question.

Mainly, after using `With` to inject the proper argument in the function at the *rhs* of `RuleDelayed`, it felt appropriate to divide functionality into different *contexts*/packages.

Namely, package `A.wl` (see below) contains the core functionality while package `B.wl` (and possibly subsequent packages `C.wl`, `D.wl` etc) contains the patterns to match against (a different set of patterns could be encapsulated in a different package).

When I evaluate the following code segment (from a notebook)

```
Needs["B`", FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "B.wl"}]]

expression = head1["a", 9.8] head1["a", 
  head2["b", 12, 0.7] head3["c", 3], 0] head3["b", 5.9, -3] 
    head1["a", head2["b", -9, 0.5] head3["c", 11], 0.8];

h[expression]
```

function `h` returns

> ```
> {{<|"x1" -> B`Private`x1|>}, 
>     {<|"x2" -> B`Private`x2, "y2" -> B`Private`y2|>, 
>      <|"x2" -> B`Private`x2, "y2" -> B`Private`y2|>}, {}}
> ```

It seems that `f` fails to provide a match.

After *a lot* of guesswork I managed to make the code work by noticing that the symbols needed to become matched over the pattern should have a `$` appended to their name.

In order to make the code work and obtain the following result, please comment out the *second* `With` in function `f` in package `A`.

> ```
> {{<|"x1" -> 9.8|>}, {<|"x2" -> 12, "y2" -> 0.7|>, 
>      <|"x2" -> -9, "y2" -> 0.5|>}, {}}
> ```

So, my question is, what exactly is going on with what seems to be the renaming of the patterned symbols. Have I missed something or is there a problem with passing patterns between packages?

---

#### Code

Copy and paste the code of each package into a *.wl* file and save both files in a suitable folder, preferably in the same place where the notebook you're using to evaluate the code in the question body is located

**Package A**

```
BeginPackage["A`"]

  f::usage = "f";

Begin["`Private`"]

  g[tags_, values_] := Module[{op = Apply[Join]},

  If[
    (* if nothing is matched... *)
    values === {},

    (* ... return {}*)
    {}, 

    (* ... otherwise, return an association of tag-value pairs *)
    MapThread[AssociationThread[#1 -> #2]&, {tags, values}] // op
   ]
  ]

f[expression_, template_] := Module[{symbols},

  (* parts making up a template *)
  symbols = Cases[template, pattn_Pattern :> pattn[[1]], Infinity];

  (* !!! 
  With[{tags = SymbolName /@ symbols, syms = ToExpression[StringJoin[ToString[#], "$"]]& /@ symbols}, *)
  With[{tags = SymbolName /@ symbols, syms = symbols}, 

    Cases[expression, template :> g[tags, syms], Infinity]

   ]
 ]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

**Package B**

```
BeginPackage["B`"]

  h::usage = "";

Begin["`Private`"]

  Needs["A`", FileNameJoin[{FileNameDrop[$InputFileName, -1], StringJoin["A.wl"]}]]

  templates = {Global`head1["a", x1_], Global`head2["b", x2_, y2_], Global`head3["c", Global`junk[z3_]]};

  h[expression_] := Module[{},

    f[expression, #]& /@ templates

   ]

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

Comment: This is the problem: [20766](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20766/5478) and the solution is `RuleDelayed @@ Hold[template,  g[tags, syms] ]`.